# Deploy telegram bot on webhooks

Tags: python, deployment, hosting, webhooks, aiohttp

I wrote a telegram bot on webhooks, used the aiogram library version 3.0.0rc2. While writing the bot, I used ngrok to create a base url and wrote an application on aiohttp.

```
async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}")


def main():
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
    dp = Dispatcher()

    dp.startup.register(on_startup)

    app = web.Application()

    webhook_requests_handler = SimpleRequestHandler(
        dispatcher=dp,
        bot=bot
    )

    webhook_requests_handler.register(app, path=WEBHOOK_PATH)
    setup_application(app, dp, bot=bot)
    web.run_app(app, host=WEB_SERVER_HOST, port=WEB_SERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now I have a problem - I have no idea how to deploy all this, I wrote a tg bot before, but I used polling and hosted on Railway, now my subscription has ended there and I can't buy, although I sort of figured out this particular service. Apart from this, I have no experience. I've tried many different services, but I can't launch the bot in any way.
Also I do not know which IP and Port I should use
I tried Render but it doesn't support aioram 3 maybe I can manually upload aiogram there
Render on python 3.7 i need python 3.11

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Bot` is since you haven't included your imports. But reading your description I understand you want to use telegram bot with webhooks tunneled by `ngrok`

You'll need two apps running in parallel, and an SSL certificate (you don't have to create one explicitly as `ngrok` uses certificates signed by well known CA)

- An API that hosts your webhook - This will receive the messages from Telegram API
- Ngrok that tunnels the API - This will give the public endpoint for Telegram API to send messages to your API running on localhost

You can use [pyngrok](https://pypi.org/project/pyngrok/) to write a wrapper around it, start it through multiprocessing, and trigger everything with a single entrypoint.

It just so happens, I have a complete repository created as a proof of concept for this exact purpose (tried and tested)

https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook

I've used `FastAPI` run by `uvicorn` server, for my webhook and the source code supports any tunnleing app like ngrok or it's alternatives.

You can use any API or server to kick off your webhook.
One draw back I noticed during testing was, sometimes when I used `ngrok` alternatives like [expose-localhost](https://pypi.org/project/expose-localhost/), I ran into issues where the IP resolved through DNS was different from the actual tunneling server's IP. But fortunately Telegram API accepts `webhook_ip` as a parameter in its payload for you enforce an IP instead of relying on DNS resolution.

Links that I used as reference while writing my POC

https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook#references